# Angular - Creating form element and submitting from typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have an API that returns some data along with its destination website URL. In my angular component, I need to hit that API, create a form element, update the destination URL and data in the form and submit it.

Below is my code.

```
this._apiService.generateData()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        const form = `<form method="post" target="_blank" action=${response.destination}><input type="hidden" name="TestResponse" value=${response.testResponse}/></form>`;

        const node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(form , "text/html");

        const formElement = node.body.getElementsByTagName("form").item(0) as HTMLFormElement;

        formElement.submit();
      });
```

It's working fine if I add the form tag to the component's HTML file and use it on the typescript file like below.

```
this._apiService.generateData()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        const form = document.getElementById("test-form") as HTMLFormElement;
        form.setAttribute("action", response.destination);

        const inputElement = document.getElementById("test-input") as HTMLInputElement;
        inputElement.value = response.testResponse;

        form.submit();
      });
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: If you're using a form in Angular and you want Angular not consider an "Angular form" else a "normal form" you should indicate using `ngNoForm`. e.g. `<form method ="post" action="URL" target="_blank" ngNoForm >` (it's a bit hidden in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#description) -when talk about "to use native HTML5 validation, add the ngNoForm"

Comment: I added ```ngNoForm``` to the ```<form>``` tag, but nothing happens on ```formElement.submit()```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing quotation marks in action attribute?

```
action=${response.destination}
action="${response.destination}"
```

(also in your `<input value>`)

Also, is there a requirement to be using `<form>` element as a way to POST to your API?

Comment: Yes, I have to POST via ```<form>``` only